# Navigating on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a Google Map project. I need to accomplish something interactive. On the map, there will be lots of markers indicating different places and one place will be set as center. Clicking on the marker will pop up the infoWindow. On the infoWindow there will be a link named “NEXT”. Hitting that link will take the viewer to another marker place. It seems to be straight forward, so my question is there any API method to accomplish such task? Any help/suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest that you start looking at the [examples from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/). Everything you mentioned can be done with the API.

Comment: Right you are, they have lots of example done. The main issue I can not manage handling the click on infoWindow (the "next" link) as it does not have any click event or anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `domready` event of the infowindow to bind your click events, [as described here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow).

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
    // whatever you want to do once the DOM is ready
});
```